# Items list with discriminators

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, n-tier-architecture

Let's say I have an entity and a db table named `Client`.
`Client` has a foreign key - `CountryId` that connected to the `Countries` table.

`ClientA`, `ClientB` and `ClientC` inherit from `Client`.

I want to list all the clients in my system (including those with null countryId), along with their concrete types (the discriminator value) and the country name.

My query looks something like this:

```
from client in DbContext.Set<Client>()
                    from country in DbContext.Set<Country>().Where(x => x.Id == client.CountryId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where !(client is Salon)                         
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = client.Id,
                        Name = client.ClientName,
                        ClientClass = "TODO",
                        CountryName = country.CountryName
                    };
```

**My question:** How can I select the discriminator value? Note the "TODO" in the code where I'm stuck at the moment..

Thanks!

Comment: If you just want a string of the type name will `client.GetType().ToString()` not do the trick?

Comment: My bad, missed the "Concrete types" requirement... `client.GetType()` in this case?

Comment: I've already tried it with no success. I got: `System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Goes to show what I know about LINQ to Entities ;)

Answer (score 0):

discriminator column is used internally by Code First and you cannnot read/write its values from an inheritance mapping standpoint.

to get decriminator you have to create custom SQL query

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<T>("SELECT client.Id, client.ClientName, client.Discriminator, country.CountryName FROM Countries country LEFT JOIN Clients client ON country.Id = client.CountryId WHERE client.Discriminator <> 'salon'").ToList()
```

Comment: Seriously? There's no way of getting this value with LINQ?? The query in the question was simplified so I won't waste your time.. It's actually a pretty big LINQ query, so now I need to switch it to native SQL query? Maybe I better make another query to get the discriminator and that's it...